# Jsoup :eq(n) selector

Tags: selector, jsoup

I hava a test.htm page:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="partA">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="partB">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="partC">
    3
    </div>
    <div class="partB">
    4
    </div>
    <div class="partD">
    5
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want get the first div with class="partB".

```
Document doc=Jsoup.parse( new File("test.htm"), "utf-8" );
Elements select=doc.select( "div.partB:eq(0)" );
System.out.println( select.get( 0 ).html() );
```

The run exception is:

```
 Exception happens:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:546)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:321)
    at org.jsoup.select.Elements.get(Elements.java:501)
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

Instead, I got a size=0 elements. 
Any helps. Thanks~

Comment: If i change div.partB:eq(0) to div:eq(0), it works well. But I want select the first div with class partB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eq(n)` selector checks the element's sibling index, i.e. the count from the element's parent. So in your example, your selector is looking for a div with both class 'partB' and that is the first child element of its parent (the body). No such element exists, which is why you get a zero length return.

I suggest you use:

```java
Element div = doc.select("div.partB").first();
```

Which finds the divs by class and then winnows using the list accessor of Element.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Cause I need to config query expressions in a file, and select elements in runtime. So, is there other way?

Comment: There isn't a selector that counts matches. That's what the .get(n) method on Elements is for. Can you update your config file to optionally include an index / limit to the number of results used?

Comment: Thanks. I will find another way.